# Where is the index of Scanner.next() stored

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to sort through a File object using java.util.Scanner, and am wondering something. I did some print statement debugging, and was curious where the index for where the Scanner has scanned is stored.

```
System.out.println(scanner.next());
System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

These obviously print different things, but I would like to know where an index or location of the scanner is stored, as that would be useful to me.

Comment: Internally (if at all).

Comment: So there's no way for me to get the index? That seems like a useful method, that doesn't seem to be in the API

Comment: Correct. Because it operates on a stream, not some kind of index.

Comment: The index into the scanner's buffer can be gotten using reflection but I'm not sure why you would want to do that. Scanners are usually used for reading multicharacter tokens. Can you explain you reasons for wanting to do this and maybe someone can provide an alternate solution?

Comment: Ok, so basically operates the same as a forEach loop

Answer (score 0):

The scanner takes data from a stream so there is no stored index. You could imitate the current index through use of a counter, or store the data into a map and set the key as the index. Depends what you specifically need it for.